# Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected version: 3.0.0

Tags: java, android, vue.js, cordova, quasar

I am trying to build a quasar cordova app for Android. when I run the command `quasar dev -m cordova -T android` I get the error:

> Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
> ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> (recommended setting)
> ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\myUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
> (DEPRECATED) Requirements check failed for JDK 1.8.x! Detected
> version: 3.0.0      Check your ANDROID_SDK_ROOT / JAVA_HOME / PATH
> environment variables.
>
> App · Command "cordova" failed with exit code: 1  App · Updated
> Cordova config.xml  App · ⚠️  [FAIL] Cordova CLI has failed

It says I need JDK 1.8.x, but it detected 3.0.0. But I am pretty sure I have JDK 1.8 installed, when I run the bash shell command `java -version` I get:
`Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Xmx3g -Xms2g java version "1.8.0_291" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_291-b10) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.291-b10, mixed mode)`

at C:\Program Files\Java I have two folders:
jdk1.8.0_291 and jre.18.0_291

my JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_291`

I have no idea why  I can't get the app to build. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS set to something. After clearing the variable and trying again, everything worked. I read it may be due to the regex used by Execa failing to detect the correct version when using JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath" as an entry in my PATH variables to get around this